# Why is a array typedef variable considered a pointer in C

Tags: c

When doing a code review I found that the programmer had accidentally passed a typedef object directly `foo(foo)` when the function took a pointer as an argument `foo(&foo)`. For some reason it still works as long as the typedef is an array and not e.g. a struct. Can someone explain why? See the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
typedef uint8_t foo_t[3];
typedef uint8_t bar_t[2];
typedef struct __attribute__((packed))
{
    foo_t foo;
    bar_t bar;
} foobar_t;

void change_foo(foo_t foo)
{
    foo_t bar = {1,2,3};
    memcpy(foo, bar, sizeof(foo_t));
}

void change_foo_p(foo_t *foo)
{
    foo_t bar = {1,2,3};
    memcpy(foo, bar, sizeof(foo_t));
}

void change_foobar(foobar_t foobar)
{
    foo_t bar = {1,2,3};
    memcpy(foobar.foo, bar, sizeof(foo_t));
}    

void change_foobar_p(foobar_t *foobar)
{
    foo_t bar = {1,2,3};
    memcpy(foobar->foo, bar, sizeof(foo_t));
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    foobar_t foobar;
    foobar_t foobar2;
    foo_t foo;
    foo_t foo2;
    change_foo(foo);
    change_foo_p(&foo2);
    change_foobar(foobar);
    change_foobar_p(&foobar2);

    // Prints 1101 since the only method not working is change_foobar()
    printf("%d%d%d%d\n", foo[0], foo2[0], foobar.foo[0], foobar2.foo[0]);        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not the `typedef` but a general rule, that arrays decay to pointers when passed to functions.

Comment: Apparently, passing `foo` instead of `&foo` should trigger a compiler warning, as the type of the pointer is wrong. But it's *value* is correct, and it is converted implicitly to the correct type, yet considered to be incompatible.

Comment: Where does your sample code pass `foo` to a function expecting a pointer to `foo`? In `change_foo(foo)`, `change_foo` is declared to take a `foo_t`. In `change_foo_p(&foo2)`, a pointer to a `foo_t` is passed. In `change_foobar(foobar)`, `change_foobar` is declared to take a `foobar_t`. In `change_foobar_p(&foobar2)`, a pointer to a `foobar_t` is passed. None of these matches your question about passing an apparent non-pointer where a pointer is required. Are you asking about the arguments in the `memcpy` calls?

Comment: Like Eugene Sh. says, it should trigger a warning at the very least. If you don't see a warning, up your warning level. This particular warning (about incompatible pointer types) I consider worthy of upgrading to an error. Let the compiler catch it instead of code review.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer) It's not perfect, but it explains why the various uses of arrays are actually using pointers. [What's the purpose of this \[1\] at the end of struct declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47086406/364696) is also useful for reference on why you'd use a `typedef` like this on purpose, knowing it will degrade to pointers in most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

In C, an array is often automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. C 2018 6.3.2.1 3 says:

> Except when it is the operand of the **sizeof** operator, or the unary **&** operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "*array of type*" is converted to an expression with type "*pointer to type*" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Thus, when the type `foo_t` is an array of three `uint8_t`, and `x` is an object of type `foo_t`, then, in a function call such as `function(x)`, `x` is automatically converted so that the function call is equivalent to `function(&x[0])`.

However, in this case, the result is that `x` becomes a pointer to `uint8_t`. The argument must still satisfy the rules about matching argument types in the call to parameter types in the function declaration. If the function’s parameter were declared to have type pointer to `foo_t` (so it is a pointer to an array of three `uint8_t`), then the compiler should give a warning or error that `function(x)` is passing a pointer to `uint8_t`.

No such call appears in the code you included in the question, so it is unclear what you are asking about. The `memcpy` calls do contain arguments that are arrays, which are converted to pointers. These are permitted as arguments to `memcpy` because its parameters are declared to be `void *` or `const void *`, and pointers to any types of objects may be converted to `void *`.

(Additionally, a parameter declaration that is an array is automatically adjusted to be a pointer to an array element.)

Answer (score 0):

Because `foo` and `&foo` have the same value, but different type inside a function call.

The type of `foo` is `foo_t`, which is `uint8_t[2]`. This is an array type, so it *decays to a pointer to the first element* of the array when being passed to a function (`change_foo(foo)` is equivalent to `change_foo(&foo[0])`).

The type of `&foo` is `foo_t*`, which is `uint8_t(*)[2]`, i.e. a pointer that points to the entire array. As it points to the entire array, the address that is stored in the pointer, is the address of the first byte of its first element, which unsurprisingly is also the address of the first byte of the array's first element.

Thus, the calls `change_foo(foo)` and `change_foo_p(&foo)` compile to the same machine code. `change_foo_p()` invokes undefined behavior when it calls `memcpy()` with two non-matching pointers, but since it gets the same address passed in as `change_foo()` does, the undefined behavior happens to be the one you intended.