# What does it mean to typedef a struct as an array?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, typedef

The graph adjacency list code in my book is given by:

```
typedef struct vertexNode //vertexNode in an AdjacencyList
{
    VertexType data; 
    EdgeNodeType *firstEdgeNode;

} VertexNode, AdjList[MAXVEX];

AdjList adjList; # adjList is a MAXVEX-size array
```

I was confused by the last line in the typedef: `typedef struct{...} AdjList[MAXVEX]`.

The forms I can understand are:

```
typedef struct{
...
} VertexNode,

VertexNode AdjList[MAXVEX]; # AdjList is a MAXVEX-size array
```

or

```
struct{
...
} AdjList[MAXVEX]; # AdjList is a MAXVEX-size array
```

Comment: Note: There are tricks that this sort of `typedef` unlocks, like [implicit reference semantics in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47086435/364696).

Comment: Thanks so much. This previous question seems also to be my confusion. So.. the `AdjList` in `AdjList adjList` is a pointer type?

Comment: Nope. `adjList` is an array if it's a normal declaration, and a pointer only if it's a parameter to a function (just like declaring an array parameter to a function is the same as declaring a pointer parameter).

Answer (score 7):

Grammatically speaking, `typedef` is actually a storage class, like `static` or `extern`, and type alias declarations are read like variable declarations. E.g.

```
int x;
```

declares `x` to be a variable of type `int`, while

```
typedef int x;
```

declares `x` to be a type alias meaning `int`.

Similarly,

```
struct vertexNode {
    ...
} VertexNode;
```

would declare `VertexNode` to be a `struct vertexNode` variable, but adding `typedef` makes it an alias for `struct vertexNode`. Note that `struct vertexNode { ... }` (the whole thing) is a type, just like `int`. It first defines `struct vertexNode`, and then refers to it.

Additionally, array declarations may appear to behave strangely when you use commas:

```
int x, y[5];
```

declares `x` to be an `int`, while declaring `y` to be an array of `5` `int`s. (Functions and pointers are also like this.) There are other questions on this site about it.

Putting everything together, your question looks like this if you take away the `typedef`:

```
struct vertexNode
{
    VertexType data; 
    EdgeNodeType *firstEdgeNode;
} VertexNode, AdjList[MAXVEX];
```

This would declare the type `struct vertexNode`, the variable `VertexNode` of type `struct vertexNode`, and the array `AdjList` of `MAXVEX` `struct vertexNode`s. Adding the `typedef` means that `VertexNode` becomes an alias for `struct vertexNode` and that `AdjList` becomes an alias for an array of `MAXVEX` `struct vertexNode`s. Personally, I wouldn't recommend writing it like this, but I guess it's concise.

Comment: Thanks so much. I just have never seen the writing method that `typedef typeName arrayName[size]`. Now I understand the meaning of this sentence but I really don't like this kind of expression...

Answer (score 2):

This is a sample code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char STR[1024];

int main() {
    STR a = "1234";       // == char a[1024]
    printf( "%s\n", a );

    return 0;
}
```

I wrote a example with data type `char`.
You can replace it with any class or struct..

so.. Your code..

`AdjList a` is same with `VertexNode a[MAXVEX]`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your answer is really simple but effective. :)